# Rails: Show corresponding record if it exists in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a customers model, where each customer can be assigned an optional permanent number.
These numbers are unique throughout the customers model.

I want to create a table that lists numbers, and the customer names if they have been assigned to the corresponding number. Like so:

Assuming John has #2 and Jane has #4

```
# | Name
--------
1 | 
2 | John
3 | 
4 | Jane
5 |
```

My controller has this:

```
@customers_with_numbers = Customer.where("permanent_num IS NOT NULL")
```

My view will have something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% (1..15).each do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i %></td>
    <td><% somehow show the appropriate name here %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I don't know how I should go about showing the appropriate names.

Feel free to edit the question title, I wasn't sure how to word it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<td><% @customers_with_numbers.detect { |c| c.permanent_num == i }.try(:name) %></td>
```